# Aplicação Java JNLP e Banco de Dados

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Vou começar a desenvolver uma aplicação cliente/servidor e nas minhas pesquisas encontrei o Java JNLP. Eu procurei em alguns fóruns, mas não achei a resposta para esta pergunta:

Sabendo-se que a aplicação terá vários clientes que irão trabalhar ao mesmo tempo, como será o acesso simultâneo ao banco de dados? Eu preciso gerenciar isso ou a arquitetura já faz tudo pra mim?

Ainda estou com dúvida quanto ao banco de dados. Estou pensando em usar Postgres ou Firebird.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## O que é JNLP

[JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html) (*Java Network Launch Protocol*) é apenas uma forma de distribuição de um programa Java desktop facilitada por um mecanismo de carregamento de classes remotamente.

Em resumo: é como um atalho que faz o download do seu programa na hora e o executa no cliente.

Claro que não é tão simples assim. Os jars do programa precisam ser assinados digitalmente para serem carregados devidamente. Além disso, o programa JNLP [executa numa *sandbox*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/security.html), isto é, num ambiente protegido sem acesso, por exemplo, aos arquivos locais. Entretanto, é possível solicitar acesso aos recursos necessários.

## O que não é JNLP

JNLP não é uma arquitetura de desenvolvimento. O que o seu programa faz e como ele acessa dados não tem relação com esta tecnologia.

Programas desktop comumente acessam dados de duas maneiras:

### 1. Conexão direta com o banco de dados

A vantagem é a simplicidade. Problemas de uso simultâneo são tratados via transações de bancos de dados e geralmente não é necessário muita preocupação com *pool* de conexões e outras complexidades de servidores de aplicação.

A desvantagem é que cada estação de trabalho precisa de acesso direto ao servidor de banco de dados via rede (intranet), o que inviabiliza, por exemplo, o acesso remoto (internet).

### 2. Acesso a dados via Web Services

Esta segunda forma é bem interessante. Consiste em criar uma aplicação web sem interface gráfica que consegue receber requisições e retorna dados. É uma solução muito robusta se implementada com a arquitetura REST.

Então, o sistema desktop carregado via JNLP (como também qualquer outro *client*) faz requisições nos serviços disponibilizados para enviar e receber dados.

Assim a arquitetura fica desacoplada e atualizações nas regras de negócio não necessariamente impactam nas versões do cliente.

Além disso, isso impede que os clientes acessem diretamente a base de dados e causem estragos por usarem versões antigas do programa, só para citar um dos cenários problemáticos.

A maior desvantagem dessa arquitetura é que você acaba com dois sistemas para cuidar.

Comment: Obrigado pela ótima resposta @utluiz. Foi muito útil para mim.